# How do I check if a user have a specific role in a specific server through a command sent in DM in discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to check if the user has a specific role in a specific server through a command sent in DM. The server ID and the role are static and I have the ID for both. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Guild.member`:

```js
const guild = message.client.guilds.cache.get('Guild ID')

// <user> is a placeholder for the user object
if (guild.member(user).roles.has('Role ID'))
```